# Hot to list all files from a folder with XPCOM

Tags: javascript, firefox, xpcom

I want to list all images from a folder using XPCOM and iMacros. Bellow is the code I use but I get an error.

```
ReferenceError: file is not defined, line 319 (Error code: -991)
```

Here is example of code I am using.

```
   var imageurl =  "s:\\images\\";

imageurl = CheckFolder(imageurl);

alert(imageurl);

function CheckFolder(path) {

            alert(path)
            file.initWithPath(path);
            var children = file.directoryEntries;
            var child;
            var list = [];
            while (children.hasMoreElements()) {
                child = children.getNext().QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
                list.push(child.leafName + (child.isDirectory() ? ' [DIR]' : ''));
            }
            alert(list.join('\n'));
        }
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Add-ons/Code_snippets/JS_XPCOM , though `file` variable comes out of nowhere in your code.

Comment: Ok I browsed through the website. I see no solution here... what am I missing?

Comment: Edit: This actually helped. Thank you a lot. I've made a solution that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I've made from link above. You were right on the target.

//find all files in folder

```
function CheckFolder(filePath) {



    var nsFile = Components.Constructor("@mozilla.org/file/local;1", "nsIFile", "initWithPath");

    var file = new nsFile(filePath);

    //file.initWithPath(filePath);
    var children = file.directoryEntries;
    var child;
    var list = [];
    while (children.hasMoreElements()) {
        child = children.getNext().QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
        list.push(child.leafName + (child.isDirectory() ? ' [DIR]' : ''));
    }
    alert(list.join('\n'));

    return list;
}
```